# How do I group nested properties in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

My sequelize model will return an array of objects. Now each object in my array will have an id and a 'dog' object from my database. I need to group dogs by color.. how can I achieve that ?

```html
client.findAll({
                attributes: ['dogs'],
                 group: ['dogs.color']
            });
```

The above snippet won't work... It will be compiled though to:
 'SELECT "dogs" FROM "animal" AS "animal" GROUP BY "dogs"."color";'

Comment: Can you give an example of the model?  That will help really in determining what you are saying.  Since SQL does not normally allow nested values.  This either has to be stored in JSON or JSONB to be able to have nested values.

Comment: @Moosecouture yes, it is JSON inside postgress. Data looks like: [{0: {id: 1, dog: {color: "blue"}}}]

Comment: Well if it is dog... then you should be looking at dog instead of dogs.  Can I get a schema definition?

Comment: @Moosecouture there is dogs, my bad.. https://pastebin.com/m7882bAx